# How to run 'cfx xpi' after 'activate' via .bat?

Tags: batch-file, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to automatize installing of my addon. [Mozilla says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_started#Developing_without_cfx_run) that it's very simple, but:

1. I didn't find any `while` loops in .bat files or `sleep` for milisec.
2. I can't understand, how to use `activate.bat` and `cfx xpi` in one CMD window sequentially, and also use wget in other CMD after all.

How can I do even if second part? I've tried something like:

`START cmd /K "activate "cfx xpi"" && wget --post-file=tst-closing-cur-tab.xpi http://localhost:8888/`

or

`START cmd /K "activate && "cfx xpi"" && wget --post-file=tst-closing-cur-tab.xpi http://localhost:8888/`

but it always run `cfx` in CMD, not in 'virtual CMD' after `activate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this

```
call "c:\Firefox\Sdk\bin\activate.bat"
cd c:\dev-1.0.2.5-firefox\
cfx xpi
```

Comment: Holly crap. There was no need to complicate the problem (: But I also want to deactivate it and send actual version with wget. Do you know, how can I do that?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with wget. But i think you need 3 .bat file, one with xpi generating and one with sending, third run both with delay. You can do sleep in cmd like this ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul for 1 second

Comment: really. Made _xpi.bat and _send.bat, and _xpi-send.bat, there wrote: `call "_xpi.bat" && call "_send.bat"`. Works perfectly